# Equivalent to Java annotations

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

In Java I can do something like:

```
@file_pattern("**/BILLING*.csv")
@format("fixed")
@encoding("latin-1")
@missing_end_of_record_fields_supported: yes
@header: yes
@comment_char: "#"
@lineending("auto")
@BOM: yes
@max_errors: 5
Class BillingRecord extends BaseRecord

    @pos(1, 5)
    @strip("left")
    @minmax(1, 19999, "error")  // "warn" only warn, but don't increase error count
    @pattern(r"\d+", "error")
    int ID;

    @pos(6, 10)
    @strip("left")
    @decode  // from "latin-1" to utf-8
    String name;
```

and use the annotations to generate the required (optimized) source code. This is a simple example, which we later on want to expand into ETL workflows/processes. I looked at Julia's metaprogramming and macro capabilities, but struggled to find concrete examples similar to the use case.

We are not reliant on annotations if Julia provides something different. However it should be equally easy to read and comprehend, extensible, and flexible.

Thanks a lot for your ideas

Comment: Though CSV.jl has ways to specify most of what you say java's annotations class can do in specifying the fields of csv data, I don't know of any Julia macros that do exactly what the annotations do. It should be possible, but afaik has not been done.

Comment: Found a good discussion about annotations here https://blog.softwaremill.com/the-case-against-annotations-4b2fb170ed67. As mentioned, I'm open to alternative way of solving the problem, provided it is equally easy to use and equally readable. Since the example above is Java (where most annotations are applied at runtime), I'd like to point out, that I'd prefer a compile-time solution.